# Realtime Web Based Rich Text Editor

Tags: asp.net, tinymce, real-time, fckeditor, rich-text-editor

Does anybody know of a web based Rich Text Editor like TinyMCE or FCKEditor which supports realtime collaboration? I know of systems like EtherPad, but I'm interested in finding something I can embed into another application, rather than something that works standalone.

Ideally something open source, and works on the .NET platform would be great.

Cheers

Matt

Answer (score 1):

There are

- [beweevee](http://www.beweevee.com/), using .NET, but it is not open source.
- [collabedit](http://collabedit.com)

Comment: beweevee looks interesting, however collabedit looks to be more standalone, than an embeddable RTE. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 1):

While there are several all in one solutions they often tend to be a bit lacking in features. I believe this to be because building a great editor and a great collaboration infrastructure are both very difficult and require different skill sets. It's very hard to do both very well. On the other hand if you find one that meets your needs it might be the simplest approach. ProseMirror comes to mind as a good example that does it pretty well.

I prefer to take a great editor with a great API and pair it up with some real time collaboration technology. Currently [Quill](https://quilljs.com/) and [CKEditor 5](https://ckeditor5.github.io/) are great editors that have sufficient API's to enable real time collaboration. Both of them were built with collaboration in mind. You can pair them up with a realtime back end like the Google Drive Realtime API by Google or [Convergence](https://convergence.io/) offered by [Convergence Labs](https://convergencelabs.com/) (full disclosure, I am a founder at Convergence Labs). Or if you are looking for an open source alternative you can look at Together JS or ShareDB.

Answer (score 0):

For a fully javascript based solution try [etherpad](https://etherpad.mozilla.org/)!

There is a [.NET Client example on HTTP API](https://github.com/narasimhandl/EtherpadLiteDotNet/) and [a page on other examples](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/wiki/HTTP-API-client-libraries/)

Also refer this [jQuery demo](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite-jquery-plugin) that can be embedded into your existing solution on the .NET Platform